# Unitarily equivalent matrices that are also unitarily equivalent on orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oa.operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Consider two positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ on $\mathbb C^d$.
Let $\{P_i\}_{i=1}^m$ be a complete family of $m$ orthogonal projectors on $\mathbb C^d$ (i.e., $P_i^*=P_i, P_iP_j=\delta_{ij}P_i,\sum_i P_i = 1$).
For any subset $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,m\}$, let $P_S=\sum_{i\in S}P_i$.
Suppose that for all such subsets $$P_SB P_S = U_S P_S A P_S U_S^*$$ for some collection of unitaries $U_S$ (on the respective subspaces $P_S$).

Does there exists a unitary $U$ such that $B=UAU^*$ and $[U,P_i]=0$ for all $i$?

**Update**: In fact, I can allow for even stronger conditions. Namely, the condition given above can be assumed to hold true even for powers $A^k$ and $B^k$ with unitaries $U_{S,k}$ on $P_S$ with $k$ any positive integer.

Comment: No. $A$ and its transpose $B:=A^T$ satisfy your assumption, but they need not be unitarily equivalent via diagonal unitary matrices.

Comment: Indeed. That's a very nice counter-example. Thanks.